# Android Studio 1.1.0 : adding jar in library error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have just started using android studio 1.1.0 and cannot get over the problem of adding an external jar in my project.

I am building an extremely simple app that runs perfectly well as long as I don't try to add the external jar in my app module. The jar I am trying to add is named 'xstream-1.4.8.jar'. I pasted the jar file in the 'libs' folder in my app module. Then in the project explorer tab on left hand side, I right clicked on the 'xstream-1.4.8.jar' in the 'libs' section and chose the 'add as library..' option.

Now the dependencies section of *build.gradle* in the *src* folder of my app module reads as :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.8.jar')
}
```

When I build the project, it build perfectly fine without any error. But when I try to run the app, then I get the following error :

The event log reads as :

> Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 15 sec

And the messages section reads as:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic
>   (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106) ...while parsing
>   com/thoughtworks/xstream/mapper/LambdaMapper.class 1 error; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1 
> >     Information:BUILD FAILED

I have already tried cleaning the project several times, but that doesn't help. Every time I try to run the app, I get this error. I have also built a normal java project using the same .jar file in eclipse which runs perfectly without any issues. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your java project (jar) with **JDK 1.7**.

if you use JDK 1.8, set the target to 1.7

By the way,you don't need to add this line in the dependencies block of your build.gradle.

```
compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.8.jar')
```

This line is enough.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

You can use:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```